# Flask_SQLAlchemy Initialization, Sessions vs Engine

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

New to flask and web apps, can anyone help me understand how sessions will be handled?

Here I am initializing the flask app and then passing the app to SQLAlchemy.

My understanding is the db engine is being created so I can then start running transactions against my DB. The current code runs and does what is expected but I am not sure if this is a good approach if multiple sessions are being created for each transaction.

In part of the lookup_user() function, I am having to do multiple DB actions in order to add the entered user or update the existing one in the system. Is there a better way to handle  sessions with flask_sqlalchemy?

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = pg_dbstring
db = SQLAlchemy(app)


@app.route('/player', methods=['POST'])
def lookup_user():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        entered_user = request.form["username"]
        user_check = db.session.query(Users).filter(Users.username == request.form["username"]).count()
        if user_check > 0:
            user_id = db.session.query(Users).filter(Users.username == request.form["username"]).with_entities(Users.userid)
... 
Code continues
```

Answer (score 1):

Flask_Sqlalchemy takes care of the sessions for you, see [app context](https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/3.0.x/contexts/). Your session is scoped to your request, so while you can do multiple transactions per request, you wont create multiple sessions.